# Black background on scroll in Safari

Tags: html, css, reactjs, safari

I have a black line when I overscroll over viewport up/down/left/right app in Safari. In Chrome this line is white.

I have `"theme_color": "#ffffff"` in my `manifest.json` but this issue still appears in Safari.

Any way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it will help someone, don't forget to check

`<meta name="theme-color" content="your color" />` in `index.html`

The issue was there